# CPAN thinks an outdated module is up to date

Tags: perl, cpan

```
$ sudo cpanm Heap::Priority
Heap::Priority is up to date. (0.01)
```

The current version is 0.11. I'm new to CPAN so I'm getting really frustrated. What's wrong and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I have the converse problem: currently, a set of 4 modules that CPAN thinks are out of date, even though they've been updated regularly most times I've checked CPAN in the last month or two, because I keep forgetting which ones they are.  Fixing those problems is a nuisance too.

Answer (score 15):

0.11 is an unauthorized release, a CPAN upload by someone not designated as allowed by the owner of Heap::Priority.  To install alpha/beta or unauthorized releases, you explicitly specify the author and full distribution name/version:

```
cpanm FWOJCIK/Heap-Priority-0.11
```

Update: I thought you needed to include the .tar.gz (or other extension) too, but when I tried it, it worked without; this may vary by perl/cpanm version?